# Create x number of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Lets say I have this below.

```
int arrays = 0;

cin >> arrays ;

for(int i = 0; i < arrays ; i++)
{
        ????? Not sure what to do here.
}
```

And I want to create x number of arrays the user entered with 39 elements(40). How would I create this `forloop` to create 4 arrays? for example it would make `array1` `array2` `array3` `array4`

Comment: I dont know how to try this

Comment: Try creating vector of vectors instead: `std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec;` (also #include <vector>) [check here for an example](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=189221)

Comment: int array [39]; But how can i get them each a different name?

Comment: I want arrays for this .

Comment: Vectors achieve a very similar thing. Must you use arrays? Have you been told to use arrays?

Comment: Its for practice im just wanting to practice with arrays

Comment: @tonyjah5353 why are you using C++ then? Why not C?

Answer (score 2):

```
int arrays = 0;

cin >> arrays ;

int *ptr = new int [arrays]; //Make sure to validate arrays against errors
                             //and don't forget to de-allocate using delete[] when done

for(int i = 0; i < arrays ; i++)
{
        ptr[i] = i;
}
```